# Expect method to be called on class instance within function

Tags: typescript, jestjs

Hi I am trying to assert a function has been called on a instance of a class that is instantiated by a file. Here I have a file that creates a new instance of the class `Usecase` and then has a function that calls a method on this instance. I am testing this file and I want to assert that it has called the method on the class instance. I have wrote up a simplified setup of my attempt so far below. However it shows that `usecase.submitTaxes` has never been called despite it being called (I've even put log statements to confirm).

My suspicion is that the `usecase` in `index.test.ts` and `usecase` in `index.ts` are different instantiations and therefore I cannot assert that the method has been called as technically the `usecase` in `index.test.ts` hasn't been called. But I don't understand how I can get a handle such that I can write the expect line on an instance that is created within the file I am testing itself?

Normally I would work around this with dependency injection but I can't use dependency injection here as this is the first file that is loaded (it's a Lambda).

It's possible that there is no way to do this without DI but if anyone has any ideas for a solution that will be much appreciated.

```js
//usecase.ts
export default class Usecase {
  async submitTaxes(): Promise<void> {
    await dependency.x();
  }
}

// index.ts
import Usecase from "usecase";

const usecase =  new Usecase(...);

export const handler = async (event) => {
  await usecase.submitTaxes();
}

// index.test.ts
import { handler } from "../../../src/index";
jest.mock("../../../src/usecase");

describe("Test", () => {
  let usecase: Usecase;
  beforeAll(() => {
   usecase = new Usecase(...); // will this be the same mock that index.ts uses?
  });
  
  it("Test", async () => {
    // GIVEN
    const event = ...;

    // WHEN
    await handler(event);

    // THEN
    expect(usecase.submitTaxes).toHaveBeenCalled(); // fails with no calls
  });
});
```

Comment: As is always the way I may I have found a solution shortly after asking the question via https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-function-api#jestmockedclass it looks like the expect could just be `expect(Usecase.prototype.submitTaxes).toHaveBeenCalled();` I'll try this out fully and write up an answer if it works as I expect it to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`will this be the same mock that index.ts uses?` - No, it is a different instance of `Usecase` mocked class.

Try to get mocked instance that is created in `index.js` file. Reference [link](https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-function-api#mockfnmockinstances).

```
import { handler } from './index'; // update this path
import Usecase from './usecase'; // // update this path
import { mocked } from 'ts-jest/utils';

jest.mock('./usecase'); // update this path

describe('Test', () => {
  let usecase: jest.Mocked<Usecase>;

  beforeAll(() => {
    // get the mocked instance
    usecase = mocked(Usecase).mock.instances[0] as jest.Mocked<Usecase>;
  });

  it('Test', async () => {
    // GIVEN
    const event = {};

    // WHEN
    await handler(event);

    // THEN
    expect(usecase.submitTaxes).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```